# d3.js force graph multiline text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have the following nodes / links json :

```
    var nodes = [
      { id: "1", label: ["data1","data2"], level: 1 },
      { id: "2", label: ["data1","data2","data3"], level: 2 },
      { id: "3", label: ["data1","data2"], level: 2 },
      { id: "4", label: ["data1","data2","data3","data4"], level: 2 }
    ]
    var links = [
        { target: "1", source: "2"},
        { target: "1", source: "3"},
        { target: "1", source: "4"}
    ]
```

The "label" attribute for each node is an array, and that array can have different lengths for each node.
I want to generate as many text elements in the "textElements" variable as array items in each node :
node 1 : 2 text elements
node 2 : 3 text elements
node 3 : 2 text elements
node 4 : 4 text elements

I am using separate text elements because I want to be able to modify font, size & color for each.

I am afraid I am stuck because I can display only the first array element for each node.
How can I loop through the label array of each node, in order to create as many text elements ?

Here's my js code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
    
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var nodes = [
      { id: "1", label: ["data1","data2"], level: 1 },
      { id: "2", label: ["data1","data2","data3"], level: 2 },
      { id: "3", label: ["data1","data2"], level: 2 },
      { id: "4", label: ["data1","data2","data3","data4"], level: 2 }
    ]
    var links = [
        { target: "1", source: "2"},
        { target: "1", source: "3"},
        { target: "1", source: "4"}
    ]
    var width = window.innerWidth
    var height = window.innerHeight
    
    var svg = d3.select('svg')
    svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
    
    // simulation setup with all forces
    var linkForce = d3
      .forceLink()
      .id(function (link) { return link.id })
      .strength(function (link) { return link.strength })
    
    var simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation()
      .force('link', linkForce)
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-570))
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    
    var dragDrop = d3.drag().on('start', function (node) {
      node.fx = node.x
      node.fy = node.y
    }).on('drag', function (node) {
      simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
      node.fx = d3.event.x
      node.fy = d3.event.y
    }).on('end', function (node) {
      if (!d3.event.active) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0)
      }
    node.fx = null
    node.fy = null
    })
    
    
    var linkElements = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
      .selectAll("line")
      .data(links)
      .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)")
    
    var nodeElements = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
        .call(dragDrop)
        .on('click', selectNode)
    
    
    var textElements = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "texts")
      .selectAll("text")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("text")
        .text(function (node) { return  node.label[0] })
      .attr("font-size", 15)
      .attr("dx", 15)
        .attr("dy", 4)
      .selectAll("text")
      
      
    simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
      nodeElements
        .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
        .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y })
      textElements
        .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
        .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y })
      linkElements
        .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
        .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
        .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
        .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
    })
    
    simulation.force("link").links(links)
     </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance.